# How to display home page last modified date in anywhere of wordpress theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

i just display my recent published and modified posts in homepage (index.php). how can i display last modified date of my home page?

Answer (score 0):

Some quick possibe solutions working in templates:

If you have a page template for the homepage you can output somewhere

```
<?php echo "Last modified on: ".$post->post_modified; ?>
```

If you work on `index.php`  of your theme

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page()){echo "Last modified on: ".$post->post_modified;}?>
```

The first example above can be used also in `single.php` or `page.php` and will show the last modified date of the current post/page you're viewing.
The second will be visible only in homepage.
To show this anywere else you can create a shortcode: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

```
function post_date_modified_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
  ob_start();
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'post'=>1),
    $atts));
  ob_start();
  $_post=get_post((int)$atts['post']);
  //echo  "Last modified on: ".$_post->post_modified;
  $datetime = new DateTime($_post->post_modified);
  echo  "Last modified on: ".$datetime->format('c'); //Returns ISO8601 in proper format
  return ob_get_clean();        
}

add_shortcode("POST_MODIFIED", "post_date_modified_shortcode");
```

Then in the content editor where you want to output the last modified date ( note that you can pass the ID of the post/page you want to ge this information ) you can use:

```
[POST_MODIFIED post=371]
```

being 371 the post ID of your homepage ( or any other post/page )
this will output something like:

`Last modified on: 2020-01-13 15:49:51`

Of course there're many more possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`the_modified_time( $format )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_modified_time/) in the loop, where `$format` is the [PHP date/time format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). If left empty it'll show in the format from your site settings.